# Get Layout Friendly URL In Liferay

Tags: java, liferay-6

I want to get a friendly URL for a layout based on layout id. For example, /web/group/page. Currently this is how I do it:

```
Layout layout = LayoutLocalServiceUtil.getLayout(groupId, false, layoutId);

String groupFriendlyUrl = GroupLocalServiceUtil.getGroup(groupId).getFriendlyURL(); //will output /group
String layoutFriendlyUrl = layout.getFriendlyURL(); //will output /page
String webFriendlyUrl = String.format("/web%s%s", groupFriendlyUrl, layoutFriendlyUrl); //will output /web/group/page
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to do this where I can the full path, /web/group/page with one method.

Comment: `themeDisplay.getScopeGroup().getPathFriendlyURL(layout.isPrivateLayout(),themeDisplay)+themeDisplay.getScopeGroup().getFriendlyURL()+layout.getFriendlyURL();` how about this code?

Comment: I was hoping there's a Util class. But this is good too. Thanks!

Comment: I can see your point, expecting a Util function doing this. Unfortunately, you'll have to wrap this code yourself in a custom function, if you need to call this frequently. Personally, I've created a utility Project, and use the exported .jar in all my portlets

Comment: Exactly what I'm doing now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have `plid` (Page layout Id), use `getLayoutFriendlyURL()` like below:

```
Layout selectedLayout = LayoutLocalServiceUtil.getLayout(plid);
String url = PortalUtil.getLayoutFriendlyURL(selectedLayout, themeDisplay);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `ThemeDisplay theme = (ThemeDisplay) getPortletRequest().getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);`
2. `final long GROUP_ID = theme.getLayout().getGroupId();
   Layout destinationLayout = LayoutLocalServiceUtil.getFriendlyURLLayout(GROUP_ID, false, friendlyUrl);`
3. `Layout layout = LayoutLocalServiceUtil.getLayout(destinationLayout.getPlid());
       String completeUrl = PortalUtil.getLayoutFullURL(layout, getThemeDisplay());`